# Problem connecting with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It's the first time i'm using PDO just for testing purpose.
But a strange error occurred and googling it, it seems to be weird.

Here's my database testing class

```
class db extends PDO
{
    # Our instance.
    private static $db = NULL;

    # Calling the connector.
    public static function connect()
    {
        if (self::$db === NULL)
        {
            $class = __CLASS__;
            self::$db = new $class();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

    # Connector.
    public function __construct() 
    { 
        $dns = 'mysql:dbname='.reg::get('db-name').';host='.reg::get('db-host');
        self::$db = new PDO($dns, reg::get('db-username'), reg::get('db-password'));
        reg::delete('db-password');
    }

    # Quick reporting
    public function reportError($array)
    {
        if ($this->db != NULL) { echo 'Myself getting horny'; } // Just for testing, i'm not getting horny because of a mysql database connection!
    }

}
```

Then executing the following code:

```
$db = new db();
$row = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = :id')->execute(array('id' => 1));
echo $row['value'];
```

It shows me the following error:

```
Warning: PDO::prepare() [pdo.prepare]: SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called in myfile.php on line 39
```

Considering line 39 as

```
$row = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = :id')->execute(array('id' => 1));
```

Comment: @andre matos, yes, i did. The same exactly error appears.

Comment: Why is the connect method there? Why are you checking if `$db` is null and not `self::$db`? Why are you doing `self::$db = new db();`.

Comment: Not your problem yet, but you can't use placeholders for table/columns names. Only for something that evaluates to a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You code is a mess, it's probably because you're so horny...

`connect()` method - why is it there?:

```
if ($db === NULL)
```

should be:

```
if (self::$db === NULL)
```

---

```
self::$db = new $class();
```

So, if `$class == __CLASS__ == db`, you are doing `self::$db = new db();`, doesn't seem right.

---

You can't use PDO to prepare an identifier, like a table or a column.

```
$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM :table WHERE id = :id')->execute(array('table' => 'test', 'id' => 1));
```

Should be:

```
$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE id = :id')->execute(array('id' => 1));
```

---

Try this:

```
class db extends PDO
{
    private static $db = null;

    public static function singleton()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$db) === true)
        {
            self::$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.reg::get('db-name').';host='.reg::get('db-host'), reg::get('db-username'), reg::get('db-password'));
        }

        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

Like this:

```
$result = db::singleton()->prepare('SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE id = :id')->execute(array('id' => 1));

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I did corrected it but i still get the error. Also how am i supposed to be able to use all the PDO methods and be able to get the db singleton instance every time i want by calling db::singleton()/db::connect() ?

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: PS, you don't really need a class for this, a simple function would have the same effect: `function singleton() { static $db = null; if (is_null($db)) { $db = new PDO(/*...*/); } return $db; }`.

Comment: Tried but it shows me nothing. Neither if i var_dump() $result.

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: Weird. Try enabling error reporting by adding to following to the top of your script: `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Also, is the `reg` class defined? Is the `reg::get()` method defined as static and returning something? Try replacing the `reg::get()` calls with valid values and try again.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, i found the error of the blank page by myself, it was not related to this. I re-tried your code and it returns 'bool(true)' that means it worked fine. Thanks. Last question before giving accepted answer: Why `$result = db::singleton()->prepare('SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = :id')->execute(array('id' => 1))->fetch();` doesn't work?

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: Because the `execute()` method only returns either true or false, and `fetch()` - like `fetchAll()` act on a PDOStatement object. You have to do: `$result = db::singleton()->prepare('...'); $result->execute('...'); print_r($result->fetch());`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if this is your answer, as it seems to be unrelated to the error message, but I do not think you can pass in a table name as a bound parameter. What happens if you put a hard-coded table name in the place of `:table`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a static 'connect' constructor, that makes a db-object in (static), and returns it. But you also make a new db() yourself.

The prepare statement uses `self::$db`, so tries to call the static made variable. I'm not really sure how your code is supposed to work, combining some sort of singleton/static form with an object form.

But that seems to be the trouble

Comment: Wait, we are not able to combine db::getInstance() (<- singleton?) and object form?

Answer (score 1):

Your singleton pattern is *all wrong*. Your constructor should be `private` and you should use static instances of `$db`. Refer to this [singleton example](http://www.tech-lull.com/php-tips/pdo-singleton-class).